# Access Google Search tools faster

Tags: google-search

A feature in the Google Search I use often is the specification of the search area (in my case Switzerland) to find a product in my country.

But this important feature has been hidden in some "search tools" and then again a dropdown list to choose it.

Some weeks ago it was just one click - now it's 3 click and need to search the button and look at the nice animation...

**Can I change the Google UI so that adding search parameters is fast again?**

[image: screen shot of search menus]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greasemonkey with Firefox and [a userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/152796) finally got Google back the way it should be!

Comment: Great - exactly what I wanted. With `Greasemonkey` for Firefox or in my case `Tampermonkey` extension for Chrome and installed that skript and the search tools are back again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No matter how Google changes its interface you can try to get used to this advanced search technique: `site:ch` which will limit the results to a .ch domain name.

So you can search: `laptop bag site:ch`

Comment: hmm - but site:ch (for Switzerland, sz is Swaziland :-)) will limit all results depending on the top-level domain. But there are really many websites with .com .org or others that are located in Switzerland - so it is not the same result setting "Pages from Switzerland" or "site:ch"

Comment: true indeed FiveO, edited my answer, and yes, it will limit the organic results to the .ch TLD

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set it up here

http://www.google.com/preferences#languages

Although you may need an account for it to always remember you (depending on if you delete cookies regularly I guess).

Comment: Well this limits the result in term of language - that's not suitable for me. Already in our small country we have 4 official languages - so search by language is not really possible. And I also want see english websites (so a fifth language) from switzerland in the search results...